# Issue with same Pipe component declarations in child modules

Tags: angular, typescript, import

I want to declare pipe in parent module and use it in child modules.

```
@NgModule({
  // Pipe which I want to declare in all child modules
  declarations: [ ThisIsPipe ],
  imports: [ ChildModuleOne, ChildModuleTwo],  
})
```

How can I use It child modules?

Because if I declare it twice I got error

> Uncaught Error: Type ThisIsPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: ChildModuleOne and ChildModuleTwo!
>   Please consider moving ThisIsPipe to a higher module that imports ChildModuleOne and ChildModuleTwo.
>   You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes 
>   ThisIsPipe then imports that NgModule in ChildModuleOne and ChildModuleTwo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create another module where you put the pipe and then import that module where you want to use that pipe.

One directive, component, or pipe can always belong only to exact one NgModule but this NgModule can be imported to as many modules as desired.

Comment: Is it possible to use parents declarations from child modules?

Comment: No, you have to import all modules you want to use declarations from directly. You can put several reusable components, directives and pipes together into an NgModule. You can also create an NgModule (A) that export other NgModules (B, C, D) so that you can import B, C, D by just adding A to imports of your current module.

Answer (score 0):

As `Günter Zöchbauer` answer, 
**Find Example here**

[Angular 2 - Pipe reuse in multiple modules - error not found or duplicate definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015057/angular-2-pipe-reuse-in-multiple-modules-error-not-found-or-duplicate-defini)